# What is the value of x on this right triangle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I'm trying to find the value of x on this right triangle but I have no idea how to find it, I took this exercise from a test and I know the answer but I do not know how to figure out the answer, could someone help me?

[image: The right triangle]

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with the computer language *Mathematica* and should be removed.

Comment: Ok, I already flagged it.

Comment: Just remove it without flagging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
4/1.6 = 3/x
x = (1.6*3)/4
x = 1.2
```

I don't know why I did this.

Comment: Thank you! Now I'll try to understand why does it make sense.

Answer (score 1):

using similar triangle ratios,

x/1.6 = 3/4

x = 1.2